# Neo4j Spring Relationship cannot be hydrated, it work after findAll()

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data

I am new to neo4j + spring data

I want to query the relationship by node

My Query to get relationship

```
@Query("MATCH p=(k:KEYWORD)-[r:KW_VERB]-() where id(k)= {0} return r ")
public List<KeywordVerb> findByStartNode(long id);
```

When call this method, it is fail:

> GraphEntityMapper - Relationship (7985)-[KW_VERB]->(7986) cannot be hydrated because one or more required node types are not mapped to entity classes

But I use the same function after findAll(), it works

```
Iterable<KeywordVerb> keywordVerbs2 = keywordVerbDao.findAll();
List<KeywordVerb> keywordVerbs = keywordVerbDao.findByStartNode((long) 7985);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message means the *start* and/or *end* node of the relationship r are not mapped in current session. After calling `findAll()` the nodes get loaded into the session and it is possible to map them.

To fix this simply return start and end node with your relationship:

```
MATCH p=(k:KEYWORD)-[r:KW_VERB]-(n) WHERE ID(k)= {0} RETURN r,k,n
```

or use `startNode`, `endNode` functions, if you find this more readable:

```
MATCH p=(k:KEYWORD)-[r:KW_VERB]-(n) WHERE ID(k)= {0} 
RETURN r,startNode(r),endNode(r)
```

Comment: I am not sure, I remove findAll() and change to findOne(),
it is work too

Comment: Yes, all queries generated for `findAll` or `findOne` return the needed nodes and relationships - that's why it works.